# Custom 404 page for invalid request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I have implemented custom error pages in an MVC4 application. Basically I've added the following to my Web.Config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Index"/>
</customErrors>
```

Unfortunately, if someone uses a request that adds a path to a route the redirect doesn't take place. For example I have a Document method that takes an ID on the controller Content. The following request is valid:

```
/Content/Document/1
```

I get the 404 displayed when someone calls an url like this:

```
/BlaBla
/Content/BlaBla
```

Some users manage to add `/BlaBla` after the ID:

```
/Content/Document/1/Blabla
```

This is the case where my custom 404 page is not shown. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CatchAll - Route solved the problem. A question with an answer which made me find the solution:

[MVC 4 catch all route never reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527740/mvc-4-catch-all-route-never-reached)